# Android get the amount of data send to remote server

Tags: android, android-volley

I send a file to a remote server with "Volley plus" and I want to add a ProgressBar to inform the user of the sending progress.

I don't find how to get the amount of byte sended.

If it's possible I prefer to avoid the use of TrafficStats.

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this in file uploading code..

take buffer of perticular size ,

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

read your file in FileInputStream..

```
 final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
```

start reading inputstream of size buffer,

```
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
```

Add this already read buffer to totalRead

```
        totalRead += read;
```

write that read buffer to output stream..

```
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
```

now use total filesize (totalSize) to determine completed file transfer size..

```
    long totalSize = uploadFile.length();
```

after writing to outputStream ,calculate percentage by below formula

```
int percentage = (int) ((totalRead / (float) totalSize) * 100);
```

complete code Something looks like this below code

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        try {
            final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            long totalRead = 0;
            long totalSize = uploadFile.length();

            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                totalRead += read;
                int percentage = (int) ((totalRead / (float) totalSize) * 100);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);

                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (lastProgressUpdateTime == 0 || lastProgressUpdateTime < now - 100) {
                    lastProgressUpdateTime = now;

                    Log.e("", totalRead + " " + " " + percentage);

                    if (listener != null)
                        this.listener.onUpdateProgress(percentage, totalRead);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            outputStream.flush();
        }
```